# When data saved in ViewRoot gets released from memory?

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I am using the following methods to save and retrieve data in ViewRoot on jsf 1.2 application:

```
private static final String DATA_KEY="dataKey";

public static Object retrieveData(String key)
    {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        if(context == null)
            return null;
        UIViewRoot view = context.getViewRoot();
        if(view == null)
            return null;
        Map map = (Map)view.getAttributes().get(DATA_KEY);
        if(map != null)
            return map.get(key);
        else
            return null;
    }

    public static void saveData(String key, Object data)
    {
        Map map = (Map)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getAttributes().get(DATA_KEY);
        if(map == null)
        {
            map = new HashMap();
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getAttributes().put(DATA_KEY, map);
        }
        map.put(key, data);
    }
```

I use those functions heavily in a lot of my beans to be able to use same data in both init and post of my request beans, so I was wondering when the values stored in ViewRoot gets released from memory, does it released when the user session is over, or when the request is over.

And does the heavily use of it can make memory leak? Also should I change the data key for each bean or use same data key?

Comment: @Tiny, i added the jsf2 tag so that if jsf2 has better way of doing that people should tell

Comment: UIViewRoot is a subclass of UIComponent and is the root of view. It should be perfectly okay to save data there. UIVIewRoot itself is saved in session. In 2.x one would use ViewScoped bean instead of this.